# Canning question

Tags: canning

I was canning chicken enchilada soup in the pressure canner at 10 pounds of pressure. I walked out of the room and went to the restroom and when I came back it was down to 8 pounds of pressure. It literally was five minutes.
I turned the gas back up. Got it back up to 10 pounds of pressure within a minute.
Do I have to start the process all over again?

Answer (score 3):

See below for an excerpt from the [*USDA Complete Guide to Home Canning*](https://www.nifa.usda.gov/about-nifa/blogs/usdas-complete-guide-home-canning), Part 1: *Principles of Home Canning*, where they say that if the pressure falls below the required pressure, you must raise the pressure to the proper level and start timing again from the beginning.

[image: e]

Comment: Sorry...made an edit here, but then realized we have a question on this already.  So, I believe it is a duplicate.